# Handling multiple lists with if/else condition - recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

i have many lists which contain 1 or more objects, and if there is more then 1 object in the list, it should do something. When there is only 1 object in the list, then take the second list and do the same. This should happen for 4 lists.
This is my Solution, but i think this is a bad solution. Is there a far better way on handling this code?

```
if (list1.Count > 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        DoSomething(list1);
    }
else
{
    if (list2.Count > 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
        {
            DoSomething(list2);
        }
    else
    {
        if (list3.Count > 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.Count; i++)
            {
                DoSomething(list3);
            }
        else
        {
        ...
```

Many thanks and best regards,
Joerg

Comment: Use an array of lists (or better, a list of lists) and nested loops?

Comment: You have 4 lists or more than 4?

Comment: Btw, you can use `else if` instead of `else{...}`

Comment: Should it "do something" once for the first list that matches, or individually for each item in that list?

Comment: i have only 4 lists @Jon for each item

Comment: Do the 4 list have the same type of objects?, the DoSomething() is the same for all list? if so, create a method ProcessList() and pass the candidate list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.Linq;

// create an enumerable "list" of your lists (however many there are):
var lists = new[] { list1, list2, list3, … };

// find the first list that has more than 1 element:
var list = lists.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Count() > 1);

// if there is such a list…
if (list != null)
{
    // … then `DoSomething` to each of its items:
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        DoSomething(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: This would become even easier if instead of `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, etc. you had a `lists` array to begin with…

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use same psuedo-code style as OP. The logic replicates the original, but in condensed form and with advantage of easily adding lists to the master list array (as suggested by @Benjamin).

It is assumed that DoSomething is a single function applied to the first list which has Count > 1. If you wanted to apply a custom function per list, you could create another array for holding the function to call for the corresponding list.

```
listArray = new[] {list1, list2, list3, list4}; // you can add more as needed to this master array

for (int i = 0; i < listArray.Count; i++)
{
     if (listArray[i].Count > 1)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < listArray.Count; i++)
         {
             DoSomething(listArray[i]); 
         }

         break; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check first which list you want to use:

```
var lists = new[]{ list1, list2, list3, list4 };
var list = lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Count > 1);
if(list != null)
{
     list.ForEach(l => DoSomething(list));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need the first list for which Count > 1.
Also, inside the for-loop, you're saying `DoSomething(list1);`. I think it should be DoSomething(list1[i]);

```
var lists = new [] { list1, list2, list3, list4 };
var target = lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Count() > 1);
if (target != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < target.Count; i++)
    {
        DoSomething(target[i]);
    }
} else {
    //...
}
```